# Error after creating new activity in ANDROID STUDIO (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So I created a new activity called "Menu", but it gives the following error in the menu.kt file, and yes, I have an activity_menu file created. See following image:
[image]

What should I do? Thank you in advance

Full code:

```
package com.example.native_productivityapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View


class Menu : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu)
    }
}
```

**SOLVED:**
JUST NEEDED TO RESTART AND REBUILD

Comment: is `activity_menu.xml`  in layout folder ?

Comment: @ManoharReddy it is

Comment: check if you imported correct `R`

Comment: post up your full java code including imports @Prensapjaimo

Comment: Make sure you have imported com.example.native_productivityapp.R

Comment: @Wini I just posted the full code

Comment: @p.mathew13 that didnt work

Comment: Do a rebuild..if that didn't work clear caches and restart ur android studio

Comment: @ManoharReddy I imported android.R and it didnt work

Comment: @Prensapjaimo restart android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environmental problems，restart Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to clean the project: Build -> Clean Project, or try to invalidate the cache and restart (File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart)